# regex for match and repleace pattern in strings

Tags: php, regex

I have file content containing the following pattern:

```
blabla  12:345 blaaak
```

The question is, how can I use regex to make them as:

```
blabla 12:34 5 blaaak
```

I know this is a simple question, but I can only think of using:

```
\d{2}:\d{3}
```

but how to reformat the matched pattern?
any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $string = "blabla  12:345 blaaak";
    echo $string;   

    $string = preg_replace("/(\d{2}:\d{2})(\d{1})/", "$1 $2",$string);
    echo $string;

?>
```

Output:

```
blabla 12:345 blaaak
blabla 12:34 5 blaaak
```

Comment: @Victor.Li there is a checkbox on left to the answer, you should really click on it since the answer helped to solve the problem. Thanks.